# adding a "last updated" to a "static" home screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My iPhone app has a home screen, with icons to various sections of the app. One of them opens a webview containing a simple tumblr blog. I'd like to be able to display the blog's "last updated" date underneath the icon. Not a super complex request...any ideas on doing this simply and easily?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you update the tumblr blog through the UIWebView or through a web service from your app? If from your app, then you know when the update was done and can store it in user defaults or some other place, and use that in a UILabel. If its from the web, then you wont know because it will have happened without any side effects to let you know of the update. If that is the case, you might see if there is a web service that lets you fetch the last update time and use that web service to get it and update your label that way.